# CodeStar/CodeBuild Role X trusts too many services, expected only 1

Tags: node.js, aws-codebuild, aws-codestar

I'm testing out CodeStar with the default NodeJS & serverless template. For some reason this template defaults to nodejs 8.11 for the runtime environment and 6.10 for the build environment.

In order to sync them I'm attempting to override the build image so that it matches. Unfortunately, I'm hitting an error:

[image]

The weird thing about this is that I don't have any roles with that name. Haven't had much to do with AWS so quite possible I'm overlooking something obvious here?

Comment: Yep, that worked mate - thanks for that. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you unselect "allow AWS CodeBuild to modify.." option, this should work for you.

Comment: Sure, but then how does unchecking that affect the build?

Comment: how to do this on terraform ?